# 1004 Runtime Error on adding Excel chart

Tags: vba, excel

Consider this code:

```
Subroutine(ByRef objExcelApp As Object)

Dim objChart As Excel.Chart<br>
Dim objChartAdd As Excel.Chart


Set objChart = Charts.Add

'Plotting graph in excel 

'After completion 
Set objChart = Nothing

End Sub
```

When I run this code, everything runs fine, and without closing application if rerun it with another report type - it prompts an error 1004 at `Set objChart = Charts.Add`

Any help, anyone can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Need some more detail.  Code as posted does not compile.  Heading should be something like Sub YourSubName (...)  Dim objChart ...<br> is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add a chart in the UI? I bet you're in a situation where a chart cannot be added (multiple sheets selected; workbook not activated; protected range active; etc).

Chris

Comment: Hi Chris, I start the application (first run) and run it - at that time I'm able to generate the charts on the Excel sheet. 
When I rerun it without restarting the application, that error pops up, I'm very much new to it - so will you please tell me how can I trace out the errors - yes you're right I'm unable to add the chart

Comment: My plan would be: Run the macro to the point where it breaks. Then stop the debugger, go back into Excel and just try hitting "insert chart". If the button is disabled, see if you can work out why inside Excel. If you see an error message, that should help too. If it works and you can insert a chart then we have a different problem!

Comment: Hi Chris, It's not a macro, its a VB program. Thats a nice tip you just shared - thank you :)

I just fixed the bug - the statement needed 
Set objchart = (EXCELOBJECT).charts.add

Now my question is, if it successfully ran for the very first run and subsequently failed in the re-run's, what logical reason justified its success in the first run? and why it failed later on. If anyone to please share their knowledge regarding the same, would be really appreciated.